# Unable to perform LAZY FETCH operation using JPA in one-to-one relationship

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, persistence, spring-orm

I am trying to lazily fetch `PetDetails` entity using JPA. However, I get `LazyInitialization Exception`. I read many solutions for this exception and came to find solution using `JOIN FETCH` in `JPQL`. Also people recommended using `Criteria` queries. However, I am trying to look for a solution if there is a way I can fetch the `PetDetails` entity the way I want without using queries directly or depending on `Criteria API` or without using `EAGER FETCH`. I might be missing something. I would appreciate for any help or suggestion. Below are the code samples:

```
1. Controller class:

    @Controller
    public class PetController {
        private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PetController.class);

        @Autowired
        private PetService petService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public void manageAndDisplayPet() {
            PetDetails petDetails = new PetDetails();
            petDetails.setName("DOG");
            Pet pet = new Pet(petDetails);
            // save
            petService.savePet(pet);

            // retrieve
            LOGGER.debug("**********************" + petService.getPet());
            LOGGER.debug("**********************" + pet.getPetDetails());
        }
    }

2. PetService class:

    @Service
    public class PetService {
        @Autowired
        private PetDAO petDAO;

        @Transactional
        public void savePet(Pet pet) {
            petDAO.savePet(pet);
        }

        @Transactional
        public Pet getPet() {
            return petDAO.getPet();
        }
    }

3. PetDAO class

    @Repository
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    public class PetDAO {
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "petcontext")
        private EntityManager entityManagerFactory;

        public void savePet(Pet pet) {
            entityManagerFactory.persist(pet);
        }

        public Pet getPet() {
            Pet pet = (Pet) entityManagerFactory.find(Pet.class, 1);
            return pet;
        }

    }

4. Pet Entity:

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_pet")
public class Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @JoinColumn(name = "pet_details")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private PetDetails petDetails;

    public Pet() {
    }

    public Pet(PetDetails petDetails) {
        this.petDetails = petDetails;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PetDetails getPetDetails() {
        return petDetails;
    }

    public void setPetDetails(PetDetails petDetails) {
        this.petDetails = petDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pet [id=" + id + ", petDetails=" + petDetails + "]";
    }

}

5. PetDetails Entity:

@Entity
@Table(name = "pet_details")
public class PetDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "pet_name")

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PetDetails [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy thing you can do is to call `pet.getPetDetails()` inside `PetService#getPet`. This solution is not very clear, but it will force JPA to fetch entity too. This is solution for your question, but not the good way anyways.

---

**What is the good way?**

The good way may depend on your particular usecase:

1. If you need this details everytime — you should use `EAGER_FETCH`
2. If you need it time to time than good solution it to use JPQL with `JOIN FETCH`
3. But the best way is to select not entites, but DTOs, which will contain whole information which your application needs and not more. It may be achieved with `SELECT NEW` expression as described [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_)